# How to correctly filter JSON file in postman?

Tags: javascript, json, api, parsing, postman

I have JSON file, which is very long (about 10k) products. My goal is to filter out only specific field, field im interested is "elkoCode" .

```
[
{
    "id": 1298995,
    "elkoCode": 1298995,
    "name": "VACUUM CLEANER ACC ADAPTER/S1 XCQCDQ01RM ROIDMI",
    "manufacturerCode": "XCQCDQ01RM",
    "vendorName": "XIAOMI ROIDMI",
    "vendorCode": "4R",
    "catalog": "VAA",
    "quantity": "0",
    "price": 24.0,
    "discountPrice": 24.0,
    "imagePath": url1.Jpeg",
    "thumbnailImagePath": "url2.Jpeg",
    "fullDsc": "",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "httpDescription": "url3",
    "packagingQuantity": 1,
    "warranty": "24",
    "eanCode": "",
    "obligatoryKit": 0,
    "reservedQuantity": 0,
    "promDate": 0,
    "promQuant": 140,
    "quantityForPrice2": "0",
    "price2": 0.0,
    "lotNumber": "",
    "copyrightTax": 0.0,
    "incomingQuantity": 140
},
{
    "id": 1288535,
    "elkoCode": 1288535,
    "name": "HEADSET NIKA TOUCH BLUETOOTH/BLACK 23554 TRUST",
    "manufacturerCode": "23554",
    "vendorName": "TRUST",
    "vendorCode": "TU",
    "catalog": "HST",
    "quantity": "0",
    "price": 24.06,
    "discountPrice": 24.06,
    "imagePath": "url.Jpeg",
    "thumbnailImagePath": "url2.Jpeg",
    "fullDsc": "Nika Touch | Type Wireless | Earbud | Bluetooth | Sensitivity 96 dB(a) | Battery Lithium-Ion rechargeable | Colour Black | Weight 0.04 kg",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "httpDescription": "url3",
    "packagingQuantity": 1,
    "warranty": "24",
    "eanCode": "",
    "obligatoryKit": 0,
    "reservedQuantity": 0,
    "promDate": 0,
    "promQuant": 0,
    "quantityForPrice2": "0",
    "price2": 0.0,
    "lotNumber": "",
    "copyrightTax": 0.0,
    "incomingQuantity": 0
},
{
    "id": 1251165,
    "elkoCode": 1251165,
    "name": "MONITOR ACC DESK MOUNT HANDLE/NM-D725HBLACK NEWSTAR",
    "manufacturerCode": "NM-D725HBLACK",
    "vendorName": "NEWSTAR",
    "vendorCode": "NW",
    "catalog": "MAS",
    "quantity": "0",
    "price": 24.3,
    "discountPrice": 24.3,
    "imagePath": "url.Jpeg",
    "thumbnailImagePath": "url2.Jpeg",
    "fullDsc": "Colour Black",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "httpDescription": "description",
    "packagingQuantity": 1,
    "warranty": "60",
    "eanCode": "",
    "obligatoryKit": 0,
    "reservedQuantity": 0,
    "promDate": 0,
    "promQuant": 0,
    "quantityForPrice2": "0",
    "price2": 0.0,
    "lotNumber": "",
    "copyrightTax": 0.0,
    "incomingQuantity": 0
}]
```

I archieved filtering with this postman Tests script:

```
json1 = JSON.parse(responseBody) console.log(json1[0].elkoCode)
```

This returns only 1 product ID to the console. Can somebody help me to retrieve all the elkoCodes? Since writing  json1.elkoCode , is returning only error. I could enter the numbers one by one, but there are too many of them, im sure there is simple way to filter them.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It returns only one product because you are accessing the first one ( `json1[0]` ). What you need is the `map` array function to only show that one field.

```js
const responseBody = '[{"id":1298995,"elkoCode":1298995,"name":"VACUUM CLEANER ACC ADAPTER/S1 XCQCDQ01RM ROIDMI","manufacturerCode":"XCQCDQ01RM","vendorName":"XIAOMI ROIDMI","vendorCode":"4R","catalog":"VAA","quantity":"0","price":24,"discountPrice":24,"imagePath":"url1.Jpeg ","thumbnailImagePath":"url2.Jpeg","fullDsc":"","currency":"EUR","httpDescription":"url3","packagingQuantity":1,"warranty":"24","eanCode":"","obligatoryKit":0,"reservedQuantity":0,"promDate":0,"promQuant":140,"quantityForPrice2":"0","price2":0,"lotNumber":"","copyrightTax":0,"incomingQuantity":140},{"id":1288535,"elkoCode":1288535,"name":"HEADSET NIKA TOUCH BLUETOOTH/BLACK 23554 TRUST","manufacturerCode":"23554","vendorName":"TRUST","vendorCode":"TU","catalog":"HST","quantity":"0","price":24.06,"discountPrice":24.06,"imagePath":"url.Jpeg","thumbnailImagePath":"url2.Jpeg","fullDsc":"Nika Touch | Type Wireless | Earbud | Bluetooth | Sensitivity 96 dB(a) | Battery Lithium-Ion rechargeable | Colour Black | Weight 0.04 kg","currency":"EUR","httpDescription":"url3","packagingQuantity":1,"warranty":"24","eanCode":"","obligatoryKit":0,"reservedQuantity":0,"promDate":0,"promQuant":0,"quantityForPrice2":"0","price2":0,"lotNumber":"","copyrightTax":0,"incomingQuantity":0},{"id":1251165,"elkoCode":1251165,"name":"MONITOR ACC DESK MOUNT HANDLE/NM-D725HBLACK NEWSTAR","manufacturerCode":"NM-D725HBLACK","vendorName":"NEWSTAR","vendorCode":"NW","catalog":"MAS","quantity":"0","price":24.3,"discountPrice":24.3,"imagePath":"url.Jpeg","thumbnailImagePath":"url2.Jpeg","fullDsc":"Colour Black","currency":"EUR","httpDescription":"description","packagingQuantity":1,"warranty":"60","eanCode":"","obligatoryKit":0,"reservedQuantity":0,"promDate":0,"promQuant":0,"quantityForPrice2":"0","price2":0,"lotNumber":"","copyrightTax":0,"incomingQuantity":0}]'

const json1 = JSON.parse(responseBody); 
const output = json1.map(item => item.elkoCode);
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Please vote to close obvious duplicates

Answer (score 0):

since Postman test scripts are javascript code you can map the results into a new array like this:

```
var results = responseBody.map(a => a.elkoCode);

console.log(results)
```

The .map method is a standard method for Arrays in javascript and for each item in the array it will only return elkoCode.

Hope this helps!

If you're interested in learning more about the .map method read this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map